# How to get the text in the left-hand div flowing around the close button on the right (to work in IE8 as well!)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I really thought I knew how to do this, and I know there are a LOT of questions about this, but I haven't seen an answer that matches my ludicrously simple case.
Here's the html:

```
<div id="examined-evidence">
    <div id="examined-evidence-details">
        <div class="heading"><p>I would like this text to float left and, if necessary, flow AROUND the close button which, ideally, would stay put in the top right corner, where most reasonable people would expect a close button to sit. Surely this should be more straight forward.</p></div>
        <div id="examined-evidence-close-button" class="button"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the css:

```
#examined-evidence {
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 10%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;    
    background-image: url('../assets/images/transparent_grey_tint.png');
    border: 1px solid #33ffff;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#examined-evidence.active {
    display: inline-block;
}

#examined-evidence #examined-evidence-details {
    background-color: #333333;
}

#examined-evidence #examined-evidence-details .heading {
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#examined-evidence #examined-evidence-details .heading p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 12px 3px 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.75em;  
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
}

#examined-evidence #examined-evidence-image {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 80%;
    width: auto;    
}

#examined-evidence #examined-evidence-image img {
    height: 80%;
}

#examined-evidence-close-button {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

...but, despite setting almost everything to inline-block, the close button div still displays BELOW the text div, in IE and in Chrome.
(And just FYI, the img src gets set from javascript, so please don't worry about that.)

If anyone has any ideas, I'm dying to show this web page who's boss. What did I screw up this time?

Comment: I've stopped using IE < 9 but I seem to recall that the answer to this is to put the Div that floats right (Close button) *before* the Div that floats left (class=heading).

This certainly works with input buttons which are inline-blocks by default.

Comment: you need to set a width on the div with the text otherwise it defaults to 100% and this pushes the button div down below it.

Answer (score 0):

Drop your close button into an inline-span inside the p element, adjust your margins, and you should be all set:

```css
      #examined-evidence {
        z-index: 1000;
        position: absolute;
        left: 25%;
        top: 10%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 80%;
        background: dimGray;
        border: 1px solid #33ffff;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }

      #examined-evidence.active {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      #examined-evidence #examined-evidence-details {
        background-color: #333333;
      }

      #examined-evidence #examined-evidence-details .heading {
        padding: 0px;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      #examined-evidence #examined-evidence-details .heading p {
        text-align: justify;
        padding: 3px 12px 3px 12px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0.75em;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        margin: 0px;
      }

      #examined-evidence #examined-evidence-image {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px auto;
        height: 80%;
        width: auto;
      }

      #examined-evidence #examined-evidence-image img {
        height: 80%;
      }

      #examined-evidence-close-button {
        background-color: red;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        height: 34px;
        width: 34px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px 15px 10px 10px;
      }
      .clear {
        clear: both;
      }
```

```html
    <div id="examined-evidence">
        <div id="examined-evidence-details">
            <div class="heading"><p><span id="examined-evidence-close-button" class="button"></span>I would like this text to float left and, if necessary, flow AROUND the close button which, ideally, would stay put in the top right corner, where most reasonable people would expect a close button to sit. Surely this should be more straight forward.I would like this text to float left and, if necessary, flow AROUND the close button which, ideally, would stay put in the top right corner, where most reasonable people would expect a close button to sit. Surely this should be more straight forward.I would like this text to float left and, if necessary, flow AROUND the close button which, ideally, would stay put in the top right corner, where most reasonable people would expect a close button to sit. Surely this should be more straight forward.</p></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @MadGab and thanks for the answer. This sounds promising but the only (unmentioned) problem is that I set the html() of the p element with jQuery and that would overwrite the close-button span, which would remove the pre-initialised angular ng-click. I'm just trying to think of a way of replacing the content of the p without affecting the span...

Comment: You should be able to make it work with the $compile service. Here's an example, but I should throw in a friendly reminder not to manipulate the DOM from the controller. For demo purposes only: https://jsfiddle.net/8g6Lrsyu/.

Comment: I had to go back to just putting the close button 'first'. So, when the text is not long enough to wrap, it at least looks OK. If the text needs to wrap, the text div gets forced down 'below' the height of the close button. Seems ludicrous to me that it's so hard to get text flowing 'around' another element, right? Isn't that, like, standard practice? If you have any ideas of how to replace just part of an element's html with jQuery, I'd be keen to hear them...

Comment: Well the solution here is based on trying to solve the challenge in the original question and is a touch overcomplicated. Tbh I wouldn't go this route myself. Instead why not just absolutely position your close icon in an element and place the content in another div adjacent, keeping everything looking clean with margins? The text may not flow around the icon, but for simplicity & sanity's sake might be a better choice.